# R: ifelse() changes more values than I want it to. Why?

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I want to create a dummy-variable that shows whether a survey respondent has indicated that they voted for a far-right party in the last election named `dat_red$RRP`. The ISSP-data I have has a variable that shows the party-family a respondent voted for (far-left, center-left, center, center-right, far-right, etc.). It is called `dat_red$party_lr`. A value of 5 in `dat_red$party_lr` should correspond to a 1 in the dummy, everything else to a 0 in the dummy. This is the part that works.

However, I saw that a vote for Donald Trump in 2016 was classified as "conservative", not as "far-right", which I want to change. (PLEASE no political discussion here, ok? This is about code). This info is in another variable called `dat_red$us_prty`, where a "6" means "voted for Trump". Now I want change `dat_red$RRP` in a way that every row (i.e., every respondent) that voted for Donald Trump gets a value of "1" in the dummy. Currently, they all have a value of 0 (which is correct if you classify Trump as conservative and not as far-right.)

I wrote the following code to achieve this:

```
dat_red$RRP <- ifelse(dat_red$us_prty == 6, 1, dat_red$RRP)
```

Or put into words: Check if `dat_red$us_prty`has a value of 6. If so, write a "1" into `dat_red$RRP`, if not keep whatever value is already in there.

The problem: Not only does this line of code change the values I want it to, but it also changes every value of people that did not vote in the US 2016 presidential elections (e.g., because they are from another country) to NA.
Here are two pictures:
a) Before I execute the line (note that 479 respondent that voted for Trump are still among the 6400 conservative voters, whereas they should end up with the other 929 far-right voters.)

[image: Before]

b) and after (The American voters have been classified as intended, but now everyone except the American respondents are NA.)

[image: after]

I suspect the error is in the last argument of my ifelse()-function, but the way I put it usually works just fine.

Thank you for your help in advance! <3

Comment: We have no data to reproduce your example, but my guess is if `ifelse` works the same as `if_else` (the latter is recommended, because it's vectorized), if `us_party` is NA, your condition cannot be evaluated, so your column will change to NA. At least, `if_else` has a fourth argument that lets you add a value for whenever this happens instead of NA

Comment: @JuanC both `ifelse` and `if_else` are vectorized, but the `NA`s seem a likely culprit.

Comment: Maybe try `ifelse(dat_red$us_prty %in% 6, 1, dat_red$RRP)`, as `%in%` will give `FALSE if the comparison is `NA`. Or more explicitly `ifelse(dat_red$us_prty == 6 & !is.na(dat_red$us_prty), 1, dat_red$RRP)`

Answer (score 1):

```
dat_red$RRP <- ifelse(!is.na(dat_red$us_prty) & 
                        dat_red$us_prty == 6,
                      1, 
                      dat_red$RRP)
```

Comment: Could you provide more explanation to your code?

Comment: you need to account for NA values is.na() is a base function that provides a vector of TRUE or FALSE for every element as to whether it is NA, and thats relevant to whether to set to 1 or to RRP